# Is it true that $|f(x)|\leq |f^2(x)|$?

Tags: functions, inequality

Is the following true for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all real functions f?
$$\left| f(x)\right| \leq \left| f^2(x)\right|$$

Also, is it true that $|f(x)|\leq |f^3(x)|$?

Comment: Note that this has nothing in particular to do with _functions_. Whether $|y|\le|y^2|$ depends only on _which number_ $y$ is; it is not influenced by $y$ being the value of a function at some $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly not: if $\lvert f(x)\rvert<1$, on the contrary $\lvert f(x)\rvert>\lvert f^2(x)\rvert$. Same answer for any power $>1$.

(I supposed you meant the square of the function, not the function composed with itself).

It's the inverse situation for roots: if $\lvert f(x)\rvert<1$,$\lvert \sqrt{\lvert f(x)\rvert}>\lvert f(x)\rvert$.

Comment: Can you reflect on the additional subquestion for the third power?

Comment: @Jason: That's done!

Comment: By the way, can I ask something irrelevant that came to my mind: Is it true for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ that $$|\sin\sin x|\leq |x|$$

Comment: Yes, because for any $x$,  $\lvert\sin x\rvert\le\lvert x\rvert$, hence , $\lvert\sin(\sin x)\rvert\le \lvert\sin x\rvert\le\vert x\rvert$.

Answer (score 0):

No, take for example any constant function $f(x) = c$ with $c \in (-1, 1) \setminus \{0\}$.